# Python class @property RecursionError

Tags: python, class, oop, recursion, properties

I want to have `@property` named `image` that when if its exist just return it simply otherwise I do some stuff and then assign it to a variable and then return it.

```py
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self, name: str):
        self.name = name

    @property
    def image(self):
        if self.image: 
            return self.image
        # Some code
        self.image = 'image url'
        return self.image
```

Error message :

```
in image 
if self.image: return self.image
[Previous line repeated 996 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `self.image` in itself, it will call the function that you are working on. This is because by defining that function with `@property`, when you try to access the property `myClassObj.image`, it will actually work by calling your function `image()`. So when you access `self.image` inside, this is where the recursion is occurring.

**TL;DR**: Don't access `self.image` inside the `image` function.

Have the actual image stored as `self._image` or something like that:

```py
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self, name: str):
        self.name = name

    @property
    def image(self):
        if self._image: 
            return self._image
        # Some code
        self._image = 'image url'
        return self._image
```